# OpenERP v7 does not send internal messages

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I have set up completely OpenERP v7 with both `Social Network` and `Project` modules.
I do create project and task with users assigned to team and/or follower, but **users never receive any internal message** about the project. The inbox of the users contains only the *Welcome* messages about OpenERP.

I need to set up OpenERP to send messages to Project Leader, Project Team and Project Follower, but I don’t find this configuration.
I’ve tried (with no success) to manage with `Configuration > Technical > Email > Subtypes`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

when you create the project 
depending on the kind of notifications you are following. You can select the kind of notification you want to receive using the checkboxes that are located below the "Follow" button:

and also go the related user and edit the email prferences and select All message

or follow this link fo rmore details

[Followers, Internal messaging](https://openerp.my.openerp.com/fr_FR/forum/Help-1/question/How-to-trigger-an-email-on-project-issue-changes-35894)